# How can we draw a interactable CIElab Color Space using python and also plot the data points (having color parameters l*,a*, b* , h and C* values)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, visualization

I want to measure the color difference between the reference and sample. And also want to show the color shift (difference) on the chart itself. For you reference below is the color space picture. Also Parameters with range and significance:

- L* [lightness - black to white]:[0 to 100]
- a* [green to red]:[-128 to 127]
- b* [blue to yellow]:[-128 to 127]
- C* [Chroma/Saturation]:[0 to 100]
- h [hue angle]:[0 to 360]

[image: CIElab Color Space]

Comment: You ideally want a [just noticeable difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) measure on your chosen coordinates. There are a heck of a lot of distinguishable not-quite whites (as any paint shade card will show) and the eye is incredibly sensitive to off flesh tones. NB Luminance channel on most 8 bit display systems is 0-255 (more on high end 10, 12 or 16 bit systems).

Comment: @MartinBrown, The difference i can find out using some formulas but i want to show the difference/shift from reference point on the chart itself as i mentioned.

Comment: You will have to define what you mean by "show the difference" then. It will take a fully calibrated workflow to get anywhere close to decent colour matching (although some paint manufacturers have got quite good at it with smart phone app cameras and a bespoke calibration card that goes around the surface to be matched.

Comment: "show the difference" mean i want to plot the shift in color values from the reference color value on the chart.